# sort a list alphabetically in a dictionary

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I've got following dictionary:

```
#original
random_dict={'list1': ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'list2': ['f', 'a', 'e'], 'list3': ['c', 'b', 'a']}
```

how do you sort the lists alphabetically in `random_dict` to get this:

```
#after sorting
sorted_dict={'list1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'list2': ['a', 'e', 'f'], 'list3': ['a', 'b', 'c']}
```

Answer (score 11):

Just call `.sort()` on each value:

```
for val in random_dict.values():
    val.sort()
```

This changes `random_dict` in-place. If you need a copy, use a dict comprehension instead:

```
sorted_dict = {k: sorted(v) for k, v in random_dict.iteritems()}
```

On python 3, replace `.iteritems()` with `.items()`.

Answer (score 0):

python 3.2

```
r={'list1': ['b', 'a', 'c'], 'list2': ['f', 'a', 'e'], 'list3': ['c', 'b', 'a']}

for i,v in r.items(): r[i]=sorted(v)
```